# Pipelines using same yaml but deploying to different subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a YAML based dev ops pipeline which currently has a service connection and subscription hard coded.

I now want to deploy to either dev or live which are different subscriptions.

I also want to control who can execute these pipelines. This means I need 2 pipelines so I can manage the security of the them independently

I dont want the subscription and service connection to be parameters of the pipeline that the user must remember to enter correctly.

My current solution:

Im using YAML templates which contain most of the configuration.

I have a  top level yaml file for each environment (dev.yml and live.yml).

These pass environment specific values to the template i.e. subscription

I have 2 pipelines. The dev pipeline maps to a dev.yaml file and the live pipeline maps to a live.yml

This approach means that for every combination of config I might have in the future (subscription, service connection etc) I need a new toplevel yml file.

This feels messy - Is there a better solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Pipelines using same yaml but deploying to different subscriptions

You could try to add the different subscriptions to different variable groups, then  reference the variable group in a template:

Variable Template:

```
# variablesForDev.yml
variables:
- group: variable-group-Dev

# variablesForLive.yml
variables:
- group: variable-group-Live
```

**dev.yml:**

```
stages:
- stage: Dev
  variables:
  - template: variablesForDev.yml
  jobs:
  - job: Dev
    steps:
    - script: echo $(TestVarInDevGroup)
```

**live.yml:**

```
stages:
- stage: live 
  variables:
  - template: variablesForLive.yml
  jobs:
  - job: live
    steps:
    - script: echo $(TestVarInLiveGroup)
```

You could check this document [Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

**Update:**

> This approach means that for every combination of config I might have
> in the future (subscription, service connection etc) I need a new
> toplevel yml file.

Since you do not want to create the toplevel yml file each time for every combination of config you might have in the future, you could try to create a **variable group** for those (subscription, service connection etc) instead of the toplevel yml file:

**dev.yml:**

```
variables:
- group: SubscriptionsForDev

stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
  - job: Dev
    steps:
    - script: echo $(TestVarInDevGroup)
```

In this case, we do not need create a new toplevel yml file when we add a new pipeline, just need add a new variable group.

Besides, we could also set security for each variable group:

[image]

**Update2:**

> I wanted to know if it was possible to avoid the 2 top level files.

If you want to avoid the 2 top level files, then the question comes back to my original answer, we need a new pipeline to contain these two yml files. We just need to add **condition** to each stage:

```
stages:
- stage: Dev
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev'))
  variables:
  - group: variable-group-Dev
  jobs:
  - job: Dev
    steps:
    - script: echo $(TestVarInDevGroup)

- stage: live
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/live')) 
  variables:
  - group: variable-group-Live
  jobs:
  - job: live
    steps:
    - script: echo $(TestVarInLiveGroup)
```

But if your two yaml files have no conditions that can be used as conditions, then you have to separate them.

Comment: In my solution I have a single repo with 2 top level yml files (dev.yml and live.yml) and some templates .

The dev pipeline  is mapped to dev.yaml (which just references the templates and passes in the hardcoded dev specific variables) and the live pipeline is mapped to live.yaml  and behaves similarily. 

This then allows me to secure each pipeline differently (i.e. who can run the pipelines).

Your suggestion seems to always run in both - since I dont think you can specify which stages in the yaml run per pipeline? 

Am I missing something?

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, Thanks for your quickly reply. If I understand you correct, we could just individually reference the corresponding variable group or variable group template in `dev.yml` and `live.yml`, check my updated answer. If not understand you correct, please let me know for free, I will keep follow :).

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any better solutions that dont require to two top level yaml files but still allow for the security constraints I mentioned? Functionally the variable groups are neater but its essentially the same solution

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, When you open your pipeline, ans select the three vertical points(More actions), select **Triggers**  and click three horizontal dots (More commands), there is an option **Security**, which you could create a group and set the permissions for this pipeline.

Comment: Isnt this the same as the "manage security" directly off the pipelines more actions?

Im unsure how this helps with my question about a better approach?

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, It seems that my understanding of your question is not completely correct, let us return to the original question, your question is to use different subscriptions in the **one** (dev or live) yml file and guarantee security?

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, Thanks for your reply. I have updated the answer with more detailed info, please check the part of **Update** for some more details. Check if it help you.

Comment: So.. I create 2 variable groups, but how do I select which variable group to use without altering the yaml? Surely I still need two top level yaml files to achieve this?

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, Do you mean that `dev.yml` and `live.yml` are both template files, and you do not want to modify them? After we add the variable group for the first time in the `dev.yml` and `live.yml` file, we no longer need to modify the file.

Comment: I have a single template file. My original solution was to have 2 top level files dev.yml and live.yml which would contain environment specific vairaibles and pass these to the template. I wanted to know if it was possible to avoid the 2 top level files. It sounds like variable groups wont help this.

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, check if the update2 answer give any help.

Comment: I think in my case this solution will add complexity, but I can see how it could work for other people.

Comment: @iasksillyquestions, Yes, it will invoke another YAML file, which seems add the complexity. But we have to do this, if we want  avoid the 2 top level files. If above answer helps you, you could accept it as answer before you get a better solution. Have a nice day!

Comment: I meant the complexity of managing branches which are purposefully different - easy to mess up a rebase for example..